# apple store showing different page in wget

Tags: web-scraping, wget

istore.apple.com live url is different that url which is downloaded using wget

Open this url in browser

https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games-action/id7001?mt=8&letter=A

You will see pagination pages like 1,2,3 etc(A will be selected).

but when i download the page using wget

wget https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games-action/id7001?mt=8&letter=A

After downloading in your system open the file you will see different page(You will not see A Selected and pagination pages will not be there).

Why this happens and how to get original page??

Comment: Use a network analyzer such as Charles Proxy to examine the request and results from the site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
wget "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games-action/id7001?mt=8&letter=A"
```

It worked for me